# How to get instagram photos with PHP by API?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Last two days I was trying to display photos from my Instagram profile by raw PHP. But I'm getting these errors.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp7\htdocs\instagram\index.php on line 29

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\xampp7\htdocs\instagram\index.php on line 29
```

I created proper **authentication** from instagram API. My requested API `clients access` is valid (`clientId, userId, accessToken`). When I failed with PHP than I tried with a JavaScript Plugin [instafeedjs](http://instafeedjs.com/). Now It’s working well. Here is my PHP code, given below:-

```
<body>
<?php
function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }

    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3550421370/media/recent/?access_token=MY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN_IS_HERE");

    $result = json_decode($result);
    foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    if(empty($post->caption->text)) {
    // Do Nothing
    }
    else {
    echo '<a class="instagram-unit" target="blank" href="'.$post->link.'">
        <img src="'.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" />
        <div class="instagram-desc">'.htmlentities($post->caption->text).' | '.htmlentities(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $post->caption->created_time)).'</div></a>';
    }
}

?>

</body>
```

Comment: Use `var_dump($result)` after and before `json_encode()`. It seems that `$result->data` is not defined.

Comment: It seems fetchData isn't returning anything.

Comment: Yes $eesult->data; is empty

Comment: I get the solution. I change the Instagram API link to garb recent post. As a multidimensional array. Any kind of information on post comment, count of a post like etc is possible to display.

https://github.com/bravotanmoy/instagram-photo-and-php/blob/master/index.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your API endpoint is wrong.
This is the API to fetch **recent media of an user** from Instagram:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Get the most recent media published by the owner of the access_token.

**Parameters**

**access_token**    `A valid access token.`

**max_id**  `Return media earlier than this max_id.`

**min_id**  `Return media later than this min_id.`

**count**   `Count of media to return.`

Read more: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self

Comment: Problem solved 

https://github.com/bravotanmoy/instagram-photo-and-php

Answer (score 8):

I get the solution. It is simple by using JSON data as a multi-dimensional array. Every kind of data is able in this array.

```
<?php
$access_token = "My_Access_Token";
$photo_count = 9;
$json_link = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?";
$json_link .="access_token={$access_token}&count={$photo_count}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$obj = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json), true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
echo "</pre>";
foreach ($obj['data'] as $post){
    $pic_text = $post['caption']['text'];
    $pic_link = $post['link'];
    $pic_like_count = $post['likes']['count'];
    $pic_comment_count=$post['comments']['count'];
    $pic_src=str_replace("http://", "https://", $post['images']['standard_resolution']['url']);
    $pic_created_time=date("F j, Y", $post['caption']['created_time']);
    $pic_created_time=date("F j, Y", strtotime($pic_created_time . " +1 days"));
    echo "<div class='col-md-4 item_box'>";
        echo "<a href='{$pic_link}' target='_blank'>";
          echo "<img class='img-responsive photo-thumb' src='{$pic_src}' alt='{$pic_text}'>";
        echo "</a>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<p>";
        echo "<div style='color:#888;'>";
            echo "<a href='{$pic_link}' target='_blank'>{$pic_created_time}</a>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "<p>{$pic_text}</p>";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: very thnks this is complete