# Instagram displaying lasts posts in IONIC 4 applications

Tags: wordpress, instagram, ionic4, instagram-api

I've developed an IONIC 4 application which uses as backend an Wordpress site. All good until I decided to display on a page my lasts instagram photos. ( So nothing fancy, just some gallery with lasts photos)

The thing is, on Wordpress I have an Instagram plugin which does that, and I'd like to know If I can use the already generated token from Wordpress in my IONIC 4 application.

The Wordpress plugin is called Edge instagram widget, and basicly I've already done the steps necessary for authenticating my website, and retrieve a valid Instagram token.

Answer (score 0):

Digging more here on SO, I stumbled upon the answer to my question. Actually the Instagram token is in my site database, so using it with [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473687/how-to-get-instagram-photos-with-php-by-api?answertab=votes#tab-top) will retrive last media posts on instagram.

You can format the output in html or json, depending how you want to treat the results.

Thank you SO